# How do you extend a class in Typescript that is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using the google maps JS API together with the `google.maps` namespace via  `npm install @types/googlemaps`.  I believe the API is loaded dynamically so the `google.maps` JS global is not available immediately.

But I don't understand why I get the runtime error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` when I try to extend `google.maps.Marker` with a `class` but not an `interface`

```
// No problem!
export interface UuidMarker extends google.maps.Marker {
  uuid: string;
}

// Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined!!
export class UuidMarker0 extends google.maps.Marker {
  uuid: string;
  constructor(uuid: string, options?: gmMarkerOptions) {
    super(options);
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }
}
```

**Alternate approach using only interface**

```
// this works
export function UuidMarkerFactory(uuid: string, marker: google.maps.Marker): google.maps.Marker & {uuid:string} {  
  return Object.assign(marker, {uuid});
}

// this fails with google is not defined!! 
export function UuidMarkerFactory0(uuid: string, options?: any): google.maps.Marker & {uuid:string} {
  if (typeof google == "undefined") return null
  return Object.assign(new google.maps.Marker(options), {uuid});
}
```

What is the best practice for extending a class that loaded dynamically?

**Additional Info**

I'm using `ionic2@RC0` which uses `rollup` to bundle all the modules. All my typescript and `node_modules` are bundled into a single `main.js` script with source maps. The actual google maps API is loaded by the `angular2-google-maps` script.

If I extend using an `interface` (which seems more typescript "friendly") what pattern can I use to create an object that fits the `UuidMarker` interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the compilation process you're not getting any errors because the compiler has access to the `google.maps` definitions that you installed using `@types`.

However, in runtime your file is probably being loaded before the `google.maps` library has loaded and so the interpreter can't find the `google.maps.Marker` object.

You need to load your file only after you know that the `google.maps` file has loaded successfully.

You don't get runtime errors for the `UuidMarker` interface because it does not exist in runtime.
Interfaces don't exist in javascript, they are only used by the typescript compiler and are not being "translated" into js.

---

You can do a trick by placing the class definition inside a function.
This way the interpreter won't execute it before this function is called, which can be after the google maps lib has loaded:

```
interface UuidMarker extends google.maps.Marker {
    uuid: string;
}

let UuidMarker0: { new (uuid: string, options?: gmMarkerOptions): UuidMarker };

function classLoader() {
    UuidMarker0 = class UuidMarker0 extends google.maps.Marker implements UuidMarker {
        uuid: string;

        constructor(uuid: string, options?: gmMarkerOptions) {
            super(options);
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }
    }
}
```

([playground code which simulates this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20gmMarkerOptions%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Marker%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20gmMarkerOptions%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(options%3F%3A%20gmMarkerOptions)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.options%20%3D%20options%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20UuidMarker%20extends%20Marker%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20uuid%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20UuidMarker0%3A%20%7B%20new%20(uuid%3A%20string%2C%20options%3F%3A%20gmMarkerOptions)%3A%20UuidMarker%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20classLoader()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20UuidMarker0%20%3D%20class%20UuidMarker0%20extends%20Marker%20implements%20UuidMarker%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uuid%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(uuid%3A%20string%2C%20options%3F%3A%20gmMarkerOptions)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(options)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.uuid%20%3D%20uuid%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Another approach, is to drop the class as you suggested and just do:

```
function UuidMarker(uuid: string, marker: google.maps.Marker): google.maps.Marker & { uuid: string } {
    return Object.assign(marker, { uuid });
}
```

---

#### Edit

This syntax:

```
type MyType = google.maps.Marker & { uuid: string };
```

Is called [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) and it means that `MyType` has everything that `google.maps.Marker` has plus the `uuid` property.

A simple example:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

type Point3D = Point & { z: number };

let p1: Point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let p2: Point3D = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
```

Comment: What is the Typescript best practice for "waiting" until the JS file is loaded before extending the `google.maps.Marker` class?

Comment: How are you loading your scripts? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I'm using `ionic2` which uses `rollup` to bundle everything. all my `ts` source ends up in a `main.js`.  The `angular2-google-maps` package is loading the actual `google maps API`. I will add it to the question.

Comment: You'll either need to load the `angular2-google-maps` lib before you load your single `main.js` file, or you'll need to break the file which contains `UuidMarker0` from this `main.js` file. Compile that one into a different file, load `main.js`, then the `google-maps` and only then the new file

Comment: added script loading to the question. But I'm wondering if I should just stick with the `interface`. What kind of pattern can I use to neatly create an object that matches the `UuidMarker` interface?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: 2 good options. I think dropping the class may be simpler, it seems I only lose the ability to test `instanceof`--but I can work around that. But what does this syntax do `google.maps.Marker & { uuid: string }`?

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: I added a 2nd, related question above. Why to I trigger a `google undefined` error if I use a `new google.maps.Marker` inside a factory method?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, my TS is a bit crap. What do I need to export to use this?

Comment: @SpaceBeers I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you want to use? What is your setup? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @NitzanTomer - Say I want to use UuidMarker in another file, I'm not following how I import it and when / where classLoader gets fired.

Comment: How you import/export depends on how your system is built. You can use a module system (requirejs, systemjs, etc) or you may not. Read the [Modules docs page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) for more information about that. As for `classLoader` it gets fired when you invoke it.