# Confusion on Intersection Types with strict type checking in Type Script

Tags: typescript, google-maps

### This question ultimately has to do with `T & U` and what a type intersection is doing.

Does it use the constructor of `T` or of `U`? Or neither or both? Is it a class or an interface? Can I still create new `T & U` objects with a constructor? Would instanceOf work? If `T & U` have different properties, each which are required, how do I create a new `T & U` object? Below is why I ask all this, thank you very much.

I have a google.maps.Marker. I wanted to add an `id` property to it with strict type checking. I figured the best way would be to extend the class. But the issue with that is google.maps.Marker isn't loaded when the class is extended, resulting in an error. See thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338662/how-do-you-extend-a-class-in-typescript-that-is-loaded-dynamically).

So, I did what was recommended on there which is:

```
type IdMarker = google.maps.Marker & { id: string };
```

This works pretty well. So first I attempted to create a new idMarker out of a marker, but it wouldn't compile due to the fact that a marker doesn't have an id property. I tried to add the id while assigning a marker with the spread operator, but that didn't work. So I made `id` an optional `id?` in the above definition, and I could assign my `idMarker: IdMarker = marker` then add the `id` property.

But, I want id to be required. So now I have this:

```
const tempMarker: any = new google.maps.Marker(options);
tempMarker.id = markerData.id;
const marker: IdMarker = tempMarker;
marker.id = markerData.id;
```

And this works for me, but I don't like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> And this works for me, but I don't like it a lot.

Create a utility e.g.

```
export class Marker {
  constructor(public options: number) { }
}

export type IdMarker = Marker & { id: string };

export function createIdMarker(options: number, id: string) {
  const marker = new Marker(options) as IdMarker;
  marker.id = id; 
  return marker;
}
```

## Theory

You might have heard `if a tree falls in the forest does it make a sound`. There is a similar programming saying `if a function does mutation internally but pure in terms of all its arguments and return value, is it pure?`.

Pure programming languages commonly come with pure data structure libraries that carry out mutations internally for performance benefits.

## More

Since you are using *instances* you cannot spread (`...`), but if it was an object consisting only of json valid literals you can use it e.g.

```
type Marker = { something: number }
type IdMarker = Marker & { id: string }

const idMarker: IdMarker = {
  ...{ something: 123 },
  ...{ id: 'foo' }
}
```